# How can you spin a pipe connected to a rotary union?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

If I have a 4 inch PVC pipe connected to a rotary union, that I want to spin at 200-300 RPM -how do I do it? It appears like the rotary unions themselves have some lateral give -- So, I would need bearings?

Are there rotary unions with built-in motors? Are there motors that can have hollow, 4 inch cores? Does it make sense to get a custom gear machined for this purpose?

Comment: Protect the pipe and use a flat belt to drive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can isolate the other side of the rotary union, and use a belt, or magnetic gears. Traditional gears will put lateral stresses on the rotary joint, which may result in buckling.